# savetxt to file giving error

Tags: python, numpy

This probably has an embarrassingly easy answer, but I'm not sure what it is.

In my python code, there is a part where I want to save an array (called "stokes_columns" which is just full of floats) into a text file.

I did this fine with the following:

```
np.savetxt('../all_pulsars_1400list/%s_1400list.txt' % pname,stokes_columns, delimiter='\t')
```

The error message I get says:

> no such file or directory: '~/all_pulsars_1400list/J0543_1400list.txt'

Where J0543 is the first variable to be used for the '%s'

but - I don't understand because of course there is no file called that - that is the file I am trying to create.

I've double checked the path and it exists.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: put your `savetext` method here

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the method? Savetxt is just a numpy command.

Comment: excuse me. i had thought that `savetext ` method has been created by you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to expand path to absolute path like this:

```
>>> import os

>>> os.path.expanduser('~/all_pulsars_1400list/J0543_1400list.txt')
'home/xxx/all_pulsars_1400list/J0543_1400list.txt'
```

Comment: Note that if the directory path does not exist this must first be created, like with mkdir().